# Extracting time, date, flight # from airplane eticket

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

**Problem**

Given (x, y) positions of every word in an flight e-ticket, extract flight numbers and corresponding destination/arrival times + dates.

**My First Try**

Use regex to look for flight numbers, dates, and times. Then match the flights with the correct dates & times using (x, y) positions. This is done with a set of rules that I came up with. The issue is that these rules are becoming longer and more complicated as I try to make it work with a variety of e-tickets.

- For example, "A320" could be "Aegean Airlines (A3) Flight 20" or the irrelevant "Airbus A320".
- Another example: "320P" could be the time, 3:20pm, or it could be part of an irrelevant code that appears in the e-ticket.

**How would you approach it? What topics should I look into?**

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? If so can you tell me which approach you have taken? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Handwritten rules are ok for such things, but you need better tools than simple regular expressions. Try out [**GATE**](https://gate.ac.uk/) framework and their **JAPE** rule engine, which is just like regexes, but operates so-called annotations (e.g. "token", "word", "noun", "number", sentence, etc.).

Here's [GATE Manual](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/thakker-jape-tutorial/GATE%20JAPE%20manual.pdf) which will give you both - quick introduction and in depth feature description. Pay attention to chapters about basic **JAPE** rules and **Gazeteers**, which are essentially dictionaries with a large number of pre-included names, e.g. cities, airports, people names, etc.